# Finding a (distribution) $p(\cdot)$ satisfying $p(x) = \int_0^\infty \exp(\lambda_1 y^2 + \lambda_2 x y) p(y) dy$ and $p(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functions, probability-distributions, exponential-function

As the title says, I'm currently trying to find a distribution $p(\cdot)$ satisfying

1. $p(x) = \int_0^\infty \exp(\lambda_1 y^2 + \lambda_2 x y) p(y) dy$
2. $\forall x < 0 : p(x) = 0$

The only way I have so far thought of trying was to search for multivariate distributions with equal marginals where the conditional distribution $p(x \mid y)$ is of the form $\exp(\lambda_1 y^2 + \lambda_2 x y)$.

Any help on how I can tackle this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried differentiating both sides of equation? Maybe this function $p(x)$ satisfies some nice and solvable ODE?

Comment: I did that. With respect to $x$ this turns (by parts) into an integral involving the antiderivative of $p$. With respect to $y$ doesn't seem to yield a helpful equation either.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\int_0^\infty p(x)\exp(-y)\operatorname d y = p(x)$$

So a solution might be some $p(\;)$ such that: $p(x)\exp(-y) =p(y)\exp(y(\lambda_1 y+\lambda_2 x))$

Comment: Great idea! But unless I'm missing something obvious wouldn't this require me to make $p(\cdot)$ a function of both $x$ and $y$?

Comment: No, it is univariate.

Comment: Ah shoot. I shall resort to the excuse of not having had a coffee yet and I'll give your suggestion a try!

Comment: The issue remains that your approach hints at having $p(y)$ of the form $\hat{p}(y) \exp(a_0 + a_1 y^2 + \ldots)$. But this choice leaves no option to remove the $\lambda_2 x y$ part in the exponent of $\exp(y(\lambda_1 y+\lambda_2 x))$.